# How to Load Components in a 3rd Level nested react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanted to load 3 sub page components instead of 'Foundation Landing' page.
Once I click on the Foundation Landing page links Foundation Sub 1, Foundation Sub 2, Foundation Sub 3 the red dotted area of 'Foundation Landing' should replace with corresponding components FoundationSubA, FoundationSubB, FoundationSubC. Please  help

```
 <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Welcomepage />} />
          <Route path="SubpageLanding" element={<SubpageLanding />}>
            {/* Subpages */}
            <Route path="Foundation" element={<Foundation />} />
            <Route path="Navigations" element={<Navigations />} />
            <Route path="UiComponents" element={<UiComponents />} />
            <Route path="Datavisualization" element={<Datavisualization />} />
            <Route path="MediaAndIlustration" element={<MediaAndIlustration />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-router-ui-cvdzpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Foundation` component is rendering links to `"/SubpageLanding/XXXX"`, so matching routes for these need to be rendered in the `"/SubpageLanding"` route so they are also rendered out in the `Outlet`.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Welcomepage />} />
    <Route path="SubpageLanding" element={<SubpageLanding />}>
      {/* Subpages */}
      <Route path="Foundation" element={<Foundation />} />
      <Route path="FoundationSubA" element={<FoundationSubA />} />
      <Route path="FoundationSubB" element={<FoundationSubB />} />
      <Route path="FoundationSubC" element={<FoundationSubC />} />
      <Route path="Navigations" element={<Navigations />} />
      <Route path="UiComponents" element={<UiComponents />} />
      <Route path="Datavisualization" element={<Datavisualization />} />
      <Route
        path="MediaAndIlustration"
        element={<MediaAndIlustration />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Fix the links in `Foundation`:

```
<NavLink to="/SubpageLanding/FoundationSubA">Foundation Sub 1</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/SubpageLanding/FoundationSubB">Foundation Sub 2</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/SubpageLanding/FoundationSubC">Foundation Sub 3</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit how-to-load-components-in-a-3rd-level-nested-react-router]

[image]

Comment: Hi Reese, Could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71870446/15916627 ? I am stuck with the solution.

Comment: Thank You @DrewReese
But how to do if it required to lead corresponding SUB tabs ? means 
click of Foundation Sub 1 should activate SUB 1 tab & its content
click of Foundation Sub 2 should activate SUB 2 tab & its content
click of Foundation Sub 3 should activate SUB 3 tab & its content
https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-router-ui-cvdzpe

Comment: @PRANAV Sorry, it not quite clear to me what your last comment is saying or asking. I can click through the UI until I get to `"/SubpageLanding/FoundationSubAll"` and see three "subsections" and each is activated when clicked on. Oh, I think I might see what you are getting at. Are you asking how to get from `"/Foundation"` to a specific subsection by clicking a specific "Foundation Sub X" link/button to navigate to `"/SubpageLanding/FoundationSubAll"` with *that* specific tab active?

Comment: @PRANAV I think this is what you are describing wanting: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-load-components-in-a-3rd-level-nested-react-router-euwurs Gist is to pass some state in the route transition for which tab should be active and using it to initialize state in the `FoundationSubAll` component.