# Change file object to normal object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file-upload, antd

Please apologize me for posting the image, but unfortunately my issue can be represented better through image only.

I am making a file upload using [antd upload](https://3x.ant.design/components/upload/) component.

Once I finished uploading files one by one using multiple upload mode, I get the result as following image.

[image]

Here the first two objects are ignored when submitting the form after file upload.

The form data for api call has been sent like this, (Content as `undefined` for first two objects but works for the last where content value was provided as binary)

[image]

**Simple working example:**

[image: Edit antd-file-upload-validation-in-reactjs (forked)]

After uploading 2 and more files, please note the `console.log(e.fileList);` in line no.28 of `demo.tsx`. The result will be like, (First object with name as File but second one as normal object)

[image]

I would like to have both object values in the same format as object. Could you please guide me why after file upload, the last one have normal object and other previous uploaded have File object?

If I upload three files then I have to call three api's in which the payloads are as follows,

Payload of first file api call https://i.stack.imgur.com/s23in.png

Payload of second api call https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHnKT.png

Payload of third api call https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqYSd.png

So only the last payload has the content as binary whereas other two are undefined which prevents the image from uploading.

Comment: Seems whatever the last item uploaded is still an `Object` instead of a `File` in whatever that `normFile` callback is receiving. If you log the updated `fileList` in an `useEffect` hook you'll see they are all `File` types. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Is all you want to convert the File to a normal object? if so you can connot convert it directly but you can create a new object and set the values your self from the original file obj. e.g. """ const fileObj = {
          uid:file.uid,
          lastModified: file.lastModified,
          lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate,
          name: file.name,
          size: file.size,
          type: file.type
        };
        setFileList((state) => [...state, fileObj]); """ something like that.

Comment: @DrewReese, Once files are uploaded I will call api for each uploaded one in which the content is passed as undefined for first n files and only for last file the content is binary. Please take a look at the comments under the answer given for the question. I have attached step by step screenshots. If I upload 3 files then for first 2, the content is not passed(undefined) down to the payload. So only last file is getting saved into DB as it is the only one have content in payload.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the sandbox, but if you need the `Object` object you could grab that and cache in state where you are logging it. Otherwise, adabuyaman's suggestion seems valid.

Comment: @DrewReese, In sandbox if we upload three files then we see the first two object as with key as File whereas for the last one we have as normal object and I feel this cause issue while uploading to the api which gives content as undefined for first two and works for the last one. So seeking help how to solve this issue as I am also not sure why it happens bro.

Comment: @adabuyaman, Converted the file object to normal object but still that gives content as undefined.

Comment: From what I could see, it was always the last added elements in that array that were `Object` objects, everything prior to it was changed into a `File` object. I was suggesting that if you needed an array of the objects that you could always grab the last added elements each time you upload a file.

Comment: @DrewReese, I just founded out the root cause for the issue bro, first two object doesn't have `originFileObj` property and the last object has `originFileObj` property. And I am trying to assign this `originFileObj` as content value in payload but it is undefined for first two. If we find solution for this to have `originFileObj` for first two as well then I think we would solve the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese, My `formData` code in the app looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylZFg.png

Comment: `originFileObj` in the "Object" appears ***to be*** the "File" object later. Are you just looking for a property in your state when creating the `formData` object that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes bro, In our code, I am assigning content value as `originFileObj as blob` but unfortunately except the last uploaded one, the other previous doesn't have this property and hence it assign as undefined. And to be more specific this issue occurs only after the implementation of the beforeUpload function which has validation for file type. Previously it was working fine.

Comment: So the solution we need to look forward was that we need to have similar object structure as like the last one for previously uploaded one which will include `originFileObj` (File object) .

Comment: No no no, I'm saying that if the object you are currently referencing doesn't have an `originFileObj` property, then the object you are referencing ***is*** the `originFileObj` object.

Comment: @DrewReese, Then how can we solve this bro. My code looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylZFg.png in which `attachmentInfo` doesn't have `originFileObj`  which is the straight forward problem I am facing now. So is it possible to make some modification in `beforeUpload` function or any other code to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a file object. You need to use `FormData` to send files. It allows you to set key/value pairs. I have created a small example with complete form submission. Also attach some screenshot.

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Upload, Button, message, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { UploadFile } from 'antd/lib/upload/interface';
import { RcFile } from 'rc-upload/lib/interface';
import { POST } from '../../../utils/https';
import axios from 'axios';

interface FormRule {
    title: string;
    attachment?: { file: RcFile; fileList: RcFile[] };
}

const Uploader = () => {
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile<any>[]>([]);
    const [form] = Form.useForm<FormRule>();

    const validateFileType = ({ type, name }: UploadFile, allowedTypes: string[] = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']) => {
        return allowedTypes.includes(type!);
    };

    const uploadProps = useMemo(
        () => ({
            multiple: true,
            beforeUpload: (file: UploadFile) => {
                const isAllowedType = validateFileType(file);
                if (!isAllowedType) {
                    message.error(`${file.name} is not PNG file`);
                    return false;
                }
                setFileList((prev) => [...prev, file]);
                return false;
            },
            onRemove: (file: UploadFile) => {
                setFileList((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item.uid !== file.uid));
            }
        }),
        []
    );

    const onSubmit = async (data: FormRule) => {
        // You cannot send files like normal data. You need to convert it into buffer...
        // Use FormData and attach everything you want to send to send to backend
        // If you are using node.js, use multer or any other package of your choice to get all files
        // and get Files from req.files and data from req.body
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', data.title);

        // Don't get attachment files from data, use fileList State because
        // it you use attachment from data, it will have all the files that
        // should be not accepted. For example, upload one png file and 1 file other than png or jpeg i.e. txt,
        // it will have txt file + png file.
        if (!!fileList.length) {
            for (const item of fileList) {
                formData.append('attachment', new Blob([item as any]));
            }
        }

        // await axios('..', { data: formData, method: 'POST' });
    };

    return (
        <Form form={form} onFinish={onSubmit} layout='vertical'>
            <Form.Item label='Title' name='title' rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item name='attachment' rules={[{ required: true }]}>
                <Upload {...uploadProps} fileList={fileList}>
                    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload png only</Button>
                </Upload>
            </Form.Item>

            <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default Uploader;
```

[image]

Comment: Also here I will call api for each uploaded one separately not all at once. After uploading all files, click on submit will call three attachment api calls if I uploaded three files and pass down separate payload for each from the list. Here the attachmentName and other properties are included for all the uploaded one but only content is not getting assigned except the last one.

Comment: Any reason for sending separate api calls for each file? You can achieve the same with a single api call. Second it should be fine if you don't get `originFileObj`. We just need the file and the file already have all the attributes that you want to attach. Just make a blob of each file just like i created a blob in `content`. Don't use `originFileObj` just use the same object and convert in into blob.

Comment: My only question is why are you attaching type, name & other attributes for a single file explicitly?

Comment: I have fixed the issue with creating a new object that has `originFileObj` . The reason I need to have type, name and other attributes is that that is how the BE api call was made and it helps in storing the information in DB.

Comment: You can get the attributes of a file on the backend side. It doesn't seem ideal to explicitly add attributes with each file. Every time when upload a file you have to attach required attributes. Best of luck

Comment: Hi Bro, Could you please take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71984940/15916627