# How to remove error message in file upload?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file-upload, upload, antd

I am making a file upload using [antd design](https://ant.design/components/upload/) and here we are allowing the user to upload only `JPEG` images.

Here we have set the rules to upload only maximum of **3** `JPEG` images.

```
rules={[
          { required: true },
          { max: 3, message: "Only 3 attachments are allowed", type: "array" }
        ]}
```

**Issue:**

Here when we upload 3 `JPEG` files, it is fine.

If we upload 4th file as `JPEG`, the error is showing which is also fine.

**But when we  upload 4th file as invalid file, the error still shows which is incorrect.**

**Steps to Reproduce:**

-> Upload 3 `JPEG` files,

-> Upload 4th file which is in another format **not JPEG**.

If you observe the results, the uploaded file will be ignored in UI but we still see the error message as `Only 3 attachments are allowed`.

[image]

See the above image for better representation. Uploading 4th file as `.html` format and hence getting error in the modal popup which is correct but the rules error message (in text after last file) still displays even though there are only 3 files in the UI.

**Working Sandbox:**

[image: Edit antd-file-upload-validation-in-reactjs (forked)]

I see the issue might be from the line **46 - 51** which has,

```
  const normFile = (e: any) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };
```

The above line returns the uploaded files hidden even though it exceeds the limit.

Kindly please help me to resolve the above issue as I am stuck for long time and big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even you see three files in UI but the error that appears below the files because you are using antd form and anything that wrapped with <Form.Item> and having a `name` attribute, it is controlled by antd form. By passing `fileList` state to Upload component, this does not mean that you are controlling the fileList and you have exactly 3 files. To prove this, let me you give an example:

**1.** Upload 3 jpeg files and get the values of attachment using `form.getFieldValue('attachment')`.
**Expected Result:** An array with 3 files, No Error Below the files

**2.** Upload one more jpeg or any file & check the attachment value with `form.getFieldValue('attachment')`
**Expected Result:** An array of files with length 4 & it should be `3 files` in the array according to you. Also an error that doesn't disappear.

There are two problems in your code.
**Problem 1:** As you said if you upload 4 file that is jpeg after uploading 3 jpeg files, i still see 4 files in UI.
**Solution:**
Don't add more files in fileList if its already have 3 files. In beforeUpload, replace `setFileList((prev) => [...prev, file]);` with the following code:

```
setFileList((prev) => {
    if (prev.length < 3) {
        return [...prev, file];
    }
    return prev;
});
```

**Second Problem:** Error doesn't disappears even you have 3 files in UI.
**Solution:** You can use onChange Function. You can check if info .fileList have length greater than 3, then just replace the form attachment value with the original fileList. I set a timeout to show the error that you can upload 3 attachments and remove the error message after 2 second.

```
onChange: (info) => {
    if (info.fileList.length > 3) {
        setTimeout(() => form.setFieldsValue({ attachment: fileList as any }), 2000);
    }
}
```

Hope this solve your issue.

**Complete Code**

```
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Upload, Button, message, Form } from 'antd';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { UploadFile, UploadProps } from 'antd/lib/upload/interface';
import { RcFile } from 'rc-upload/lib/interface';

interface FormRule {
    title: string;
    attachment?: { file: RcFile; fileList: RcFile[] };
}

const Uploader = () => {
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile<any>[]>([]);
    const [form] = Form.useForm<FormRule>();

    const validateFileType = ({ type, name }: UploadFile, allowedTypes: string[] = ['image/jpeg']) => {
        return allowedTypes.includes(type!);
    };

    const uploadProps = useMemo(
        () =>
            ({
                multiple: true,
                beforeUpload: (file: UploadFile) => {
                    const isAllowedType = validateFileType(file);
                    if (!isAllowedType) {
                        message.error(`${file.name} is not JPEG file`);
                        return false;
                    }
                    setFileList((prev) => {
                        if (prev.length < 3) {
                            return [...prev, file];
                        }
                        return prev;
                    });
                    return false;
                },
                onRemove: (file: UploadFile) => {
                    setFileList((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item.uid !== file.uid));
                },
                onChange: (info) => {
                    if (info.fileList.length > 3) {
                        setTimeout(() => form.setFieldsValue({ attachment: fileList as any }), 2000);
                    }
                }
            } as UploadProps),
        [fileList]
    );

    const onSubmit = async (data: FormRule) => {
        console.log('data');
    };

    const normFile = (e: any) => {
        if (Array.isArray(e)) {
            return e;
        }
        return e && e.fileList;
    };

    return (
        <Form form={form} onFinish={onSubmit} layout='vertical'>
            <Form.Item
                name='attachment'
                valuePropName='attachment'
                getValueFromEvent={normFile}
                rules={[{ required: true }, { max: 3, message: 'Only 3 attachments are allowed', type: 'array' }]}
            >
                <Upload {...uploadProps} fileList={fileList}>
                    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload JPEG only</Button>
                </Upload>
            </Form.Item>

            <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit'>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default Uploader;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, But unfortunately your code doesn't work. Steps to try, -> Upload 3 JPEG files one by one. Then upload 4th file in some other format **not** `JPEG` . Still the above said error occurs.

Comment: You can try the above said steps here https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-file-upload-validation-in-reactjs-forked-o982rk

Comment: I could able to see the error comes for 2 second as per set timeout, but that error itself is invalid as per the context.. Bcoz there are no files more than 3 as count in the UI, then it won't be good enough to show the message as `Only 3 attachments is allowed` ?

Comment: You did not understand the exact problem what i'm talking about. Leave the UI part. Just focus on `name="attachment"`. When you upload any number of files, you can check the form value, it gonna have all the files you have uploaded even you set rule to max of 4. Just try to console the value of attachment `form.getFieldValue('attachment')` in onChange function before the `if` statement. You will understand the issue i mention in my answer.

Comment: Now I understood the issue clearly. Thanks much for your guidance bro!.